# Adding a string for a parameter in a GETPIVOTDATA function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm really hoping someone has a solution to this.  I have a `GETPIVOTDATA` function that works well, but I want to add a string that is already formatted to be added to the `GETPIVOTDATA`.  Here is an example of the `GETPIVOTDATA` function:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of "&$O$62,$B$65,"Class",B69,"Scenario",$C$67,"Capital/Operating",$T$64)
```

Here is the string I want to add to the end of the `GETPIVOTDATA` function.

```
"Project","(C0000000046) Professional Development","Task","(300) Certifications"
```

Project and Task are the fields and "(C0000000046) Professional Development" and "(300) Certifications" are the items for that I want to add to the `GETPIVOTDATA` function before it is evaluated.

Does anyone know how to make this happen?

**UPDATED**

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hcko5owdjh1dcu/Stackoverflow%20Example.xlsx?dl=0) is an example file.

Comment: Hard to tell with that information. Post a sample file. Or, build a pivot table that shows the data, then start a formula and click the cell that has the data you want. GetPivotData will then show you the syntax.

Comment: Sure, I just uploaded an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add the new parameter to the exiting formula:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of " & $O$62, $B$65,"Class", B69, "Scenario", $C$67, "Capital/Operating", $T$64, _
"Project","(C0000000046) Professional Development","Task","(300) Certifications")
```

Here a suggestion for the split:

```
DIM strInput as String
DIM strSplit() as String
DIM strGetPivot as String
DIM intCount as Integer
strInput = "Project,(C0000000046) Professional Development,Task,(300) Certifications"
strGetPivot = "=GETPIVOTDATA(""Sum of "" & $O$62, $B$65,""Class"", B69, ""Scenario"", $C$67, ""Capital/Operating"", $T$64,"
strSplit = Split(strInput, ",")
For intCount  = 0 to UBOUND(strSplit) - 1
   strGetPivot = strGetPivot & ", """ & Trim(strSplit(intCount)) & """
Next
strGetPivot = strGetPivot & ")"
```

Comment: Right but the additional string is a result of a function so I would have to reference a cell to add the string to the parameter. That's the part I'm having a hard time with. If I just add the function result as text it works just fine but it's referencing the cell as a parameter that's the problem.

Comment: Just replace "(C0000000046) Professional Development" with the reference to the cell for this condition for "Project" and "(300) Certifications" for the condition of "Task"

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear.  the problem is that the field and related item are not in separate cells.  They are in one cell as a string.  So, if the string, "Project","(C0000000046) Professional Development","Task","(300) Certifications", is in A1, I can't just add the cell reference to a GETPIVOTDATA Field or Item parameter because the string conatins both field and items.  Does that make sense?  

That's why I'd like to just add the string at the end of the GETPIVOTDATA function, not within one parameter (field or item).

Comment: You have to add the parameters. You can split the string and then added the parameters to the function.

Comment: Yeah I think that's what I'm realizing too. Sorry to make it more complicated but the string could have a varying number of fields and items I want to add to the GETPIVOTDATA parameters. Are you aware of a way to make the GETPIVOTDATA function ignore the blank parameters? I'm open to VBA solutions too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks great!  Thanks!  One last question, how can I pass this string as the GETPIVOTDATA formula?  I've tried Application.Evaluate, but it won't work on any string larger than 255 characters.  This isn't a problem with this string, but some others will definitely be larger than 255.